# Why might wptexturize have become re-enabled?

Tags: functions, filters

For ages I've had wptexturize disabled by code in my functions.

```
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );
```

Now, it seems to be not working... smart quotes are present.

My understanding is that the above method prevents plugins from altering things, so I'm wondering where to begin with troubleshooting this.

Comment: what does it mean "prevents plugins from altering things"?

Comment: I've read that if wptexturize has been disabled by a function, some plugins can re-enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to answer my own question...

It was indeed a plugin which was causing this issue.

I'd still like to find a reliable way to globally disable wptexturize.

Comment: if you really want an answer to the second part, you should just ask a new question. probably better to give as an example what is it that happens to you right now.

Comment: @Mark Kaplun... the two parts are so closely related that another question seems superfluous. And clearly, the 'above method prevents plugins from altering things' suggestion I'd read on Stack is incorrect.

Comment: then maybe you should edit this question... it should have worked, but seems like you are using a bad plugin

Comment: @Mark Kaplun... ok, [new question added](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241454/how-can-i-reliably-and-globally-disable-wptexturize).