# How can I reliably and globally disable wptexturize?

Tags: filters, hooks

For ages I've had [`wptexturize`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/run_wptexturize) disabled by code in my functions.

```
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );
```

My understanding was that this would prevent plugins from re-enabling it, but that seems to not be correct.

Specifically filtering elements, as below, stops `wptexturize` changing things, but I'm hoping there's an alternative to applying it to each instance `wptexturize` is used.

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
```

Answer (score 4):

Plugins will be able to re-enable any filter you have switched off, if they do so **after** you are finished. So the trick is to make sure you are the last one to do something with this filter by [setting a high number, low priority](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) on it.

```
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false', 9999 );
```

Comment: In stead of 9999 you can also use `PHP_INT_MAX` to make sure you have the highest thinkable number. But I always prefer to leave some wriggle space.

Comment: Where exactly to add this line? In other articles I read best in the functions.php, in the documentation it talks about not before the 'init' has finished. But it doesn't say which init! Could I just add as first line in the wptexturize function itself 'return false;'? Wouldn't that be the real definitly unbreakable solution? (Unless a plugin is malicious in some way.) @cjbj

Comment: in the after_setup_theme hook

Comment: Do you mean AFTER the line `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentytwentytwo_support' );` in the functions.php of `\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwentytwo\functions.php` I should add the add_filter-line from your answer? So far I just put it on line 10 of `\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php`

Comment: Maybe I got it now: In the `twentytwentytwo_support`-function itself in the functions.php of `\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwentytwo\functions.php`?

Comment: I guess both my previous guesses are wrong. :/

Comment: You could dump this line anywhere in your functions.php, but the best practice would be to include it in a a function that is run  at the after_setup_theme hook. You can read more about how hooks and filters work here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265952/whats-the-difference-between-hooks-filters-and-actions/265953#265953