# Regarding a custom loop and output HTML tags

Tags: wp-query, loop

I want to make the code to display the list of the page title in footer. 
I made the following code in `functions.php`:

```
  add_action('yamada_action', 'list_page_2');

    function list_page_2() {

      global $title_yama;
      $title_yama = '';

      $args  = array(
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
      );
      $queries_yama = new WP_Query($args);
      if($queries_yama->have_posts()): while ($queries_yama->have_posts()):$queries_yama->the_post();
        $title_yama .= '<li class="aaa"><a href="' .get_permalink(). '">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
       endwhile; endif;
       wp_reset_query();
       return $title_yama;
 }
```

and I inputed in `footer.php` the following code:

```
    <?php do_action('yamada_action'); ?>
```

However, the code displays just text as title.

How should I make the code in order to output including HTML code?

Comment: You're echoing the post title and not adding it to `$title_yama`. Use `the_title( '', '', false )` where the `false` means "don't echo". See the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your advice.
I can solve this problrems as follows.

function.php

```
add_action('yamada_action', 'list_page_2');

function list_page_2() {

    $title_yama = '';

    $args  = array(
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    $queries_yama = new WP_Query($args);
    if($queries_yama->have_posts()): while ($queries_yama->have_posts()):$queries_yama->the_post();
        $title_yama .= '<li class="aaa"><a href="'.esc_url(get_the_permalink()). '">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    echo $title_yama;
}
```

footer.php

```
    <?php do_action('yamada_action'); ?>
```

I fixed it as follows.

1. delete `global $title_yama;`
2. fixed href attribute `get_permalink()` to `esc_url(get_the_permalink())`
3. fixed inside `<a>` tag `the_title()` to `get_the_title()`
4. fixed `return` to `echo`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are [confusing actions and filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265952/whats-the-difference-between-hooks-filters-and-actions) here. You are using an action. That means if you want to output some html you have to that inside the function. Now your are returning the value, but nothing is done with it.

So in the last line of your function you should have `echo $title_yama` rather than `return $title_yama`.

Also, in your code you are accessing a global variable `$title_yama`, which you are then erasing. That doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score -1):

get_permalink() returns permalink of the current post as a variable, but does not echo it out.
Try `<a href="' . echo esc_url(get_the_permalink()). '">`
instead of

```
<a href="' .get_permalink(). '">
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I made a step forward by your advice.
I can display the link and title in footer now. however, I cannot generate the link.

Comment: hmm, what do you mean when speaking about "generating the link"?
May be you should try get_the_permalink() instead of get_permalink()?
get_the_permalink() retrieves the full permalink.

Comment: Currently, although the_permalink is in href tag, my code make displaying permalink as text.

Comment: You have get_permalink() in your code. Try get_the_permalink() instead. I've edit my answer a bit. Check it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.it seems I cannot insert echo before esc_url.
it displayed error.

Comment: get_permalink and get_the_permalink do exactly the same thing...

Comment: You're right. It's aliases. My fault.

Comment: The OP is adding the `<a>` to a `<li>` that's being appended to `$title_yama`. With your code, PHP will throw a parse error.