# Set Microsoft Word links to open in new window/tab

Tags: filters, the-content

I'm unable to set Word hyperlinks to open in a new window/tab. Basically, I create a Word document and paste its contents to WordPress, and everything is there, links do work, but they don't have "**target=_blank**" attribute added to them.

I do set Target Frame option in Word, but nothing happens. I've tried using _blank and New Window values, but when looking at code the target attribute isn't added.

I tried using Ctrl + F9 trick to force my links to open in new window, but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to fix that?

EDIT: This is a Word-related issue. I'm not developing a WordPress theme, I just want to paste the text from Word into WordPress and have my links open in new window. This works perfectly with Libre Office, but not with Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this would be to build a [filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265952/whats-the-difference-between-hooks-filters-and-actions) on `the_content` that scans the pasted text for links and adds `target="_blank"`. Actually, you don't even have to build it yourself, because WP has a [built in function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/links_add_target/) to do this. All you have to do is add this line to the `functions.php` of your theme:

```
add_filter ('the_content','links_add_target');
```

Beware that if your theme is updated your `functions.php` will be replaced and your edit lost. The correct way to circumvent this would be to build a child theme.

Comment: I appreciate the replay, but this isn't Wordpress related issue. I'm not developing a theme, I just want to open my hyperlinks in new window/tab.

This is exclusively a Word-related issue.

Comment: Well, but this is an exclusively WordPress related stack...

Comment: I know, but the question was moved from SuperUser to WordPress stack.

Comment: @Mentalhead it is IMHO wordpress related as you desscribe the ends is to have target=_blank in your wordpress.
As suggested by cjbj it is wise to add this filter, as you don't have to finally worry how you paste the links into wordpress, as wordpress would do the correction if needed.
Think about it that way: if the mountain won't come to the prophet, the prophet must go to the mountain.