# Don't replace "|" with Empty String ("") when generating slugs from title

Tags: filters, slug, title

I work for an architecture company and our project names mostly go like this: `house|something`, `bridge|somewhere`, `building|whatever`.

Now, when I want to add a new project named like that, WordPress automatically converts it to `housesomething`, `bridgesomewhere` and puts that as the slug. I'd much prefer to keep some kind of separator, e.g. `house-something`, `bridge-somewhere` instead.

So, how to make WordPress convert `|` to `-` and not `Empty String` (`""`)? I'm obviously tired of doing that manually all the time.

It seems to me that it's very simple to do. It takes just a simple search and replace kind of thing if one knows where to look (in the WP core or wherever), but I haven't the slightest idea where to look, or what code to execute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When WordPress [inserts a post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), it runs the title through a filter called [`sanitize_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) to get the slug. By default there is a function called [`santize_title_with_dashes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/) attached to this filter with priority 10. This function simply strips out the `|`. If it is surrounded by spaces those spaces will be converted to hyphens.

So your task is to run a filter on the same hook before (say, priority 9) the default one and replace the `|` with `-` before it gets stripped away. Like this:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', function ( $title ) {
    return str_replace( '|', '-', $title );
}, 9 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It indeed is correct, however there was one small mistake which I  fixed and edited your post to make it right. (`str_replace()` doesn't change the subject string, it's output needs to be returned.)
Up to now I haven't really looked too much into the WP Core, but I've gone through the manual for the mentioned functions and can say this practical example elucidated a lot for me. Now I actually understand how this solution works. Thanks again and bye :)

Comment: Glad to help. Thank you for correcting the error.

Comment: Understanding actions and filters is probably the first thing to dive into when trying to understand core. I wrote a small tutorial for that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265952/whats-the-difference-between-hooks-filters-and-actions

Answer (score 1):

If you put spaces in between the words and the separator | the permalink will automatically include dashes between the words. For instance try this as your post title:

```
house | something, bridge | somewhere
```

That results in the slug:

```
house-something-bridge-somewhere
```

Comment: Thanks for your post but this isn't really the solution as it requires that I change the titles, which is simply not how the company names it's projects, i.e. there shouldn't be any spaces.