# Is my code correct to enqueue CSS on a specific page?

Tags: functions, css, hooks

I am trying to load a CSS Stylesheet to ONLY the "about" page.

I think I am 99% correct but what is wrong is the `plugins_url` - to link to the theme folder where I keep my `CSS` can I just use simply:

```
function testimonial_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_tooltip_frontend_css', url('path-to-my.css') );
} 

if(is_page( 42 )){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testimonial_style');
}
```

Is it ok that I reference it with `add_action` and then "scripts" which is is is really a style **and not** a script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: 
I hope, It will works.

**Explaination:**

In below code in **"is_page( 42 )"** where 42 is page id of **about page**. So, if about page's id will be 42 then it's enqueue the stylesheet for that page only.

Also I define particular path for this CSS file by using wordpress function  **get_template_directory_uri()**.

```
function testimonial_style() {
  if ( is_page( 42 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_tooltip_frontend_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/path-to-my.css' ); 
  }
} 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testimonial_style');
```

Let me know How it help you.

Comment: Can you explain (by editing the answer) what you did and why you changed certain parts? So henry can not just copy your code but understand the logic behind it

Comment: @kero This one is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. If it doesn't work, there's probably something wrong with your hooking order.

If you look at the [list of hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), you will see that there is no `wp_enqueue_styles` hook. So, yes, it is the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook that you are supposed to add your action to. (There is a `wp_enqueue_styles` function, but that is something different, read more about how hooks work [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265952/whats-the-difference-between-hooks-filters-and-actions)).

In  your code it is not clear where the line `if(is_page( 42 )){ ... }` resides. Normally you would put it in your theme's `functions.php` in a function that is called with the `after_setup_theme` hook. Looking again at the list of hooks you will see that `after_setup_theme` comes before `wp_enqueue_scripts`. So, at this point you can still attach functions to the latter hook.

Something in your question suggests that your are executing `if(is_page( 42 )){ ... }` in a plugin. That would still be fine (*) if it is in a function that hooks onto `init`. However, if you hook into `wp_head` you would be too late, because at that point functions hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` have already been executed.

(*) but if the plugin is executed while the theme is inactive you will get an error