# Can't understand apply_filter logic

Tags: filters

Never creates self filters before. In my plugin I have variable as array. I want another users can change this array without plugin modification. I'm trying this code in my `plugin.php`:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test plugin
*/

$arr = [
    'val',
    'val2',
    'val3'
];

$arr = apply_filters( 'my_hook', $arr );
print_r( $arr );
```

In my `functions.php` I puts this code:

```
add_filter( 'my_hook', 'modify', 10, 1 );

function modify( $arr ) {
    unset($arr[0]);
    return $arr;
}
```

I expecting output without first element, but it outputs original array with 3 values;

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Are you sure you’re adding your filter before applying it?

Comment: you write about `function.php` but the file in the theme is `functions.php` with a "s".

Comment: Are these definitely loaded in the right order? It might be worth moving your plugin.php code into an init hook so you can be sure that your my_hook implementation has loaded when you try to call it.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I posted and edition below. Is it right? I don't like `globals`, in this case it's the only way to solve my problem?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265952/whats-the-difference-between-hooks-filters-and-actions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. According to comments above, I modified my code. Now it works. Is it correct way?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test plugin
*/

$arr = [];

add_action( 'init', 'set_var_data' );

function set_var_data() {
    global $arr;

    $arr = [
        'val',
        'val2',
        'val3'
    ];

    $arr = apply_filters( 'my_hook', $arr );
}

print_r( $arr );
```