# Add head and body function for google tag manager in child theme

Tags: child-theme, wp-head

I've got a child theme activated and I don't see any head and body in my child theme to place the GTM snippet.

How do I do this? I rather not paste in the whole head and body in the child theme to overwrite the parent theme and miss out on updates.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is any good it will have the [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) hook in `header.php`. In your child theme's `functions.php` you can add an [action](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265952/whats-the-difference-between-hooks-filters-and-actions) to include anything you want. Like this:

```
add_action ('wp_head','wpse359909_add_gtm');
function wpse359909_add_gtm () {
  echo 'whatever code you want to add';
  }
```

Comment: (or better yet, put this in a custom plugin, so the child theme can still get updates)

Comment: I just wanted to avoid extra plugins as well :) 
And what about the code for body? Since Google tag manager should be place in the head and top of the body.

Comment: You'll have to choose. It's either within the `<head>` tags or at the beginning inside the `<body>` tag. You can't have both. The latter has a different hook, `wp_body_open` but not all themes implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin to make managing injected code a little easier

[image]

[image]

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>


<!-- head script here -->


<?php } );

add_action( 'wp_body_open', function () { ?>


<!-- body script here -->


<?php } );
```

**Note:** This uses the somewhat newer `wp_body_open` hook introduced in WordPress 5.2 (May 2019), make sure your WordPress is 5.2+ and that your theme isn't too old.